# Cursor Disappearing After Starting Web Browser

Tags: 12.04, xorg, mouse, chromium, cursor

## My Specification

- Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit
- Kernel 3.2.0-23-generic-pae
- VGA Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
- X.org 1.11.3
- My **/etc/X11/xorg.conf** content:

> Section "Device"
>               Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
>               Driver          "fbdev"
>               Option "HWCursor" "off"
>
> ```
> EndSection
>
> Section "Monitor"
>         Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>         Identifier      "Default Screen"
>         Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
>         Device          "Configured Video Device"
> EndSection
> ```

## The Problems

**Disappearing history:**

Just some days ago. It happened to my Chromium 25 and same now at Chromium 34. I have never experienced this since my Ubuntu 12.04 first install in 2012.

**Disappearing conditions:**

- When I hover my cursor on any element that has tooltip.
- When I scroll in any application that has scrollbar.
- When I click.
- When I right click.
- Cursor appears again if I move mouse a little bit.

**Disappearing position:**

- In all desktop I have (KDE, Unity, Openbox).
- In all GUI applications, Chromium it self and beyond.
- In Konsole too.

**Problem after starting Chromium:**

directly my cursor disappears with conditions mentioned above.

**Problem after starting Rekonq, Firefox, Konqueror, and Midori:**

not directly, but in various duration (less than 1 hour), the cursor will disappear again with conditions mentioned above.

## No Problems

- It doesn't happen at all if I don't start any browser.
- At reboot, my cursor always be normal again.

## My Attempts

- I have searched many askubuntu threads about cursor disappear, tried many things, but no luck at all.
- I have no unclutter in my system.
- I have removed **nagios, mrtg, courier-*, mailman, postfix, squid3, apache2, nfs-*, bind9**, and some packages I installed few days before this problem happened.
- I have set "off" in HWCursor line in xorg.conf.
- I have tried to disable all plugins (including Adobe Flash) on Chromium but the problems didn't change at all.
- I have tried to delete **.config/chromium/** folder on Home but the problem is still occured.
- I have tried too `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false`, but same.
- I have read standard output via `tailf /var/log/syslog` when Chromium starts, but I didn't find any strange output.
- I have asked a guy in **#freedesktop** but he said something like "it is strange, i couldn't help".
- I have created new user on Ubuntu, login there, and the problem still occured. So I think it is not an usual configuration error.
- I didn't do any kernelish thing before this problem happened.
- I never do an upgrade before this problem happened (and actually my system is OK even with no upgrade at all). No kernel upgrade, no partial upgrade, even no package upgrade.

## My Questions

- What is the real problem for me? X Server (I thought it is not)? Webkit Engine (but it is too strange an engine affects a system)? Or what?
- Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Is there any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

The real problem was apparently same with my new posted problem, [Unity 3D Suddenly Disabled Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499115/unity-3d-suddenly-disabled-ubuntu-12-04). The driver in my Ubuntu has switched to wrong driver. I don't have idea why and how.

**Solution**

Just revert the correct driver back.

**Walkthrough**

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234888

**Conclusion**

This problem was **solved**.