# Unity 3D Suddenly Disabled Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity, unity-2d

My Unity was always OK since first install in 2012. I always use Unity 3D session, never use 2D session. But now, I have only Unity 2D session. I don't want 2D session, I want my 3D session back. I don't know why, now I get `Unity 3D supported:       no` information while I always can use 3D session before.

Result from `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` command:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 8.0.2

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

Result from `dpkg -l | grep xorg-video` command:

```
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati                 1:6.14.99~git20111219.aacbd629-0ubuntu2  X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus              1:1.3.2-4build1                          X.Org X server -- Cirrus display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev               1:0.4.2-4ubuntu2                         X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-geode               2.11.13-2build1                          X.Org X server -- Geode GX2/LX display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel               2:2.17.0-1ubuntu4.4                      X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-mach64              6.9.0-1build2                            X.Org X server -- ATI Mach64 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-mga                 1:1.4.13.dfsg-4build2                    X.Org X server -- MGA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic            1:1.2.5-2build2                          X.Org X server -- Neomagic display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau             1:0.0.16+git20111201+b5534a1-1build2     X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome          1:0.2.904+svn1050-1                      X.Org X server -- VIA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl                 0.0.16-2                                 X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-r128                6.8.1-5build2                            X.Org X server -- ATI r128 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon              1:6.14.99~git20111219.aacbd629-0ubuntu2  X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-s3                  1:0.6.3-4build2                          X.Org X server -- legacy S3 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-savage              1:2.3.3-1ubuntu1                         X.Org X server -- Savage display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion       1:1.7.5-1build2                          X.Org X server -- SiliconMotion display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-sis                 1:0.10.3-3build2                         X.Org X server -- SiS display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb              1:0.9.4-2build2                          X.Org X server -- SiS USB display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-tdfx                1:1.4.3-4build2                          X.Org X server -- tdfx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-trident             1:1.3.4-2build2                          X.Org X server -- Trident display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa                1:2.3.0-7build2                          X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
```

Result from `lshw -c video` command:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:50 memory:dd000000-dd3fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:e000(size=64)
```

## Question

- What is actually my problem? Why approximately in before I can use 3D and now can not?
- How to get back my Ubuntu 3D session?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

The actual problem was Ubuntu switched to use wrong driver. In this case, `NVIDIA Noveau llvmpipe`.

**Solution**

Switch Ubuntu to use the correct driver. In this case, `Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2`.

**Walkthrough**

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234888

**Conclusion**

This problem was solved.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem (maybe you should accept your answer?) Please can you add full instructions to solve? A link to a page where if I scroll down a lot I eventually find a dump of your bash history is not very helpful in my opinion...